# auto copy selected text and don't copy another text before paste last copy , then paste using double mouse click, autohotkey code

Tags: autohotkey

is There a Autohotkey code that work like this :
copy selected text automatically and doesn't copy another selected text before paste first one
also can paste text using "mouse double left click" instead "ctrl+v"

for now i have a code that just copied one line of selected text automatically and doesn't copy all selected text.

Comment: You could write a script that will assign a function to ctrl+c. That way, you can control whether to copy or not, based on a state you set in your program.

Comment: You ought to show the portion of code that you have that doesn't work and explain both what happens, and what you want to happen.  When you say "automatically" do you mean that upon selecting some or a block of text your autohotkey code immediately sends it into the clipboard once you are done selecting? Or are you triggering a autohotkey script that then copies it?  Copying a block of text to the clipboard should be trivial so i don't understand why there would be any limit to one line.  Pls explain . . .

Comment: Actually i need a autohotkey function to do copy selected text to clipboard (all of selected text) and doesn't copy another selected text untill first clipboard be paste.

Comment: And another function to paste clipboard : replace ^+v with ^+^ (double ctrl )

Comment: You can use an `#If` hotkey for copy and set/reset a variable to keep track of when something is pasted. If it is you can reset the variable and allow text to be copied again - block copying with `$^c::Return` - if you want something more fancy you could check the OnClipboardChange() function.